# Building Docker image including IPython Notebook and EE?

Tags: python, javascript, google-earth-engine, jupyter-notebook, docker

I'm starting to play with EE, already tried a bit of Javascript API. Now trying the Python one. So I found https://github.com/tylere/docker-tmpnb-ee and git cloned it, then from the terminal I did

```
docker build -t ee .
```

and got stuck at

```
Step 22 : RUN conda install --yes ipython-notebook terminado && conda clean -yt
 ---> Running in 12e9f87e8799
Fetching package metadata: ....
Solving package specifications: ..............
```

What may I do to keep going?

Not sure if that Docker image is still relevant since last commit is from 2015.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The tylere/docker-tmpnb-ee repository is not longer being maintained. Development has moved to https://github.com/gee-community/ee-jupyter-contrib